# Systemd - Invert Conditions in unit file?

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I'm attempting to make a systemd service that should only start if a certain file *doesn't* exist on the file system.

If I use `ConditionPathExists` this will make the service start only when the file in question exists, which is the opposite behavior of what I want.

Is there a way to invert these conditions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use `!` to negate the condition:

```
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=!/some/path/to/some/file
```

It's [in the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html):

> With `ConditionPathExists=` a file existence condition is checked before
>   a unit is started. If the specified absolute path name does not exist,
>   the condition will fail. If the absolute path name passed to
>   `ConditionPathExists=` is prefixed with an exclamation mark ("`!`"), the
>   test is negated, and the unit is only started if the path does not
>   exist.

Comment: Yup, definitely there, looks like I just glazed over it.